# Server 2012 Essentials not seeing PC after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: domain, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-8.1, essentials-2012-r2, windows-10

I have Server 2012 Essentials R2 configured with a regular old domain, and several Windows 8.1 machines joined to this domain.

I created a Windows 10 install USB using the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and proceeded to upgrade my Windows 8.1 machine to Windows 10 Pro. This all went without a hitch, and as far as I can tell my machine is still connected to the domain, all mapped drives and permission are still working etc...

The only problem is that my 2012 Server Essentials can no longer see my machine, take backups, check the updates status etc.... If I open the Dashboard on 2012 and check my PC in the devices tab, it says it is unable to connect and that it may be offline. If I try a start a backup of the PC it says the same thing. When I check the properties of PC it still says it is running Windows 8.1 (obviously because that's the last thing it was running when it saw it last)

I have not been able to find anything online regarding this problem, in fact all I can find is people using the same process as me and it working fine(although none explicitly mention if Server 2012 is able to see the PC afterwards)

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: The right way to do this would have been to research this **before** you upgraded the client.

Comment: @joeqwerty I did research this. I also tested on my own PC before doing the entire network as I am not an idiot. Like I said, all the info I found said this procedure works(and it did). The problem is with the Client Connector as pointed out by JamesRyan below. I am unable to find ANYWHERE on the MS technet sites that explains the procedure for upgrading domain connected machines to Windows 10 Pro. So if you could please point me to the MS document that explains this procedure I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually install the client connector as detailed at http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2015/07/23/client-connector-availability-with-windows-home-server-small-business-server-and-windows-server-essentials-for-supported-client-os.aspx

Comment: Yeah I just came across that, thanks. The connector for Windows 10 64 bit just seems to hang on my PC. I will give my machine a restart and try again shortly.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure seems to be

1. on the client pc leave the domain
2. delete the client pc from the server dashboard
3. remove the connector software from the client. Navigate to here: Control Panel / Programs / Programs and Features / Installed Updates / Windows Server Essentials Connector (Thx to [TinkerTry](https://tinkertry.com/superguide-windows-server-2012-r2-essentials))
4. re-run the connector https://*server*/connect

This does make the back up and Launchpad work again
It doesn't make the server correctly see the client computer - OS type / update status / security status

It is undocumented, somewhat unsatisfactory and rather laborious.